# setting image view frame dynamically

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uitableview, uiimageview

In my app i am sending certain number of images from my device to other device.I achieved all this .Now what i want is that when i send only 1 image to other device ,then the frame of the image view should be the full screen.If i send 2 images then the frame should be like this;-2 images covering the whole scree.So the frame should change dynamically according to the number of images sent.Currently i am using table view to display the received images .What other option could be the best to achieve my target.Please help .Anyone done this type of work before ,please i need your help.

Thanks,
Daisy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
CGFloat   screenWidth    = 320.0;
CGFloat   screenHeight   = 460.0;

NSArray   imageNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Picture1.png", @"Picture2.png", nil];
NSInteger numberOfImages = [imageNames size];

for (NSInteger j = 0; j < numberOfImages; ++j)
{
    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames objectAtIndex:j]]];
    [image setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, screenHeight / (CGFloat)numberOfImages * (CGFloat)j, screenWidth, screenHeight / (CGFloat)numberOfImages)];
    [self addSubview:image];
    [image release];
}
```

This example lists the images vertically. When you want also a horizontal list, then you have to use maths.
The code is not tested.

Comment: :-this will only set one image right?i want to set the images which i will send dynamically .please i am a newbie in this .please help

Comment: I edited the code, so now you can add images to the array by their name and the it's automatically.

Comment: thanks alot friend ,i will try this an update you and will acept teh answer ,,ok thanks

Comment: [image setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, screenHeight/(CGFloat)numberOfImages * (CGFloat)j, screenWidth, screenHeight/(CGFloat)numberOfImages)];

Comment: pointer vale used where a floating point value was expected


ths is error ,please help

Comment: Change this 'NSInteger numberOfImages = [imageNames size];' to 'NSInteger numberOfImages = [imageNames count];'. I can't see another error.